# ORACLE EXEC SQL EXECUTE USING invalid cursor

Tags: oracle

What is different this two codes of oracle proc?

`start = 1, end = 2`.
`PRINT_SQL_ERROR` print `sqlca.sqlcode` and `sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc` when an error occured.

First One, `EXEC SQL PREPARE` AND `EXEC SQL EXECUTE` located inside for syntax.
Every time, PREPARE AND EXECUTE performed.

```
memset(iQuery, 0x00, sizeof(iQuery));
sprintf(iQuery, "INSERT INTO ACCT_BALANCE VALUES (:sno, :sno, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, :sno, 
:sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, 'UPP', 'LOW', 'STT', SYSDATE, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, 
:sno, :sno )");

for ( sno = start ; sno <= end ; sno ++ )
{
    EXEC SQL AT :sAT PREPARE INSERT_STMT FROM :iQuery;
    EXEC SQL AT :sAT
      EXECUTE INSERT_STMT USING :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, 
      :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno;
    printf("[sno]=%d\n", sno);
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    {
        PRINT_SQL_ERROR("[ERROR] Insert Execute Failure!");
        return -1;
    }
    EXEC SQL AT :sAT COMMIT;
}
```

Output is

```
[sno]=1
[sno]=2

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ACCT_BALANCE;

       COUNT(*)
---------------
              2

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01
```

Second, `EXEC SQL PREPARE` located outside for syntax and `EXEC SQL EXECUTE` located inside.
Only one time PREPARE performed, and EXECUTE will be performed every time.

```
memset(iQuery, 0x00, sizeof(iQuery));
sprintf(iQuery, "INSERT INTO ACCT_BALANCE VALUES (:sno, :sno, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, 
:sno, 'UPP', 'LOW', 'STT', SYSDATE, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno )");
EXEC SQL AT :sAT PREPARE INSERT_STMT FROM :iQuery;

for ( sno = start ; sno <= end ; sno ++ )
{
    EXEC SQL AT :sAT
      EXECUTE INSERT_STMT USING :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, :sno, 
      :sno, :sno;
    printf("[sno]=%d\n", sno);
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
    {
        PRINT_SQL_ERROR("[ERROR] Insert Execute Failure!");
        return -1;
    }
EXEC SQL AT :sAT COMMIT;
}
```

Output is

```
[sno]=1
[sno]=2

[ERROR] Insert Execute Failure!
SQLCODE : -1001
ERROR MSG : ORA-01001: invalid cursor


SQL> SELECT * FROM ACCT_BALANCE;

ACCT_BALANCE_ID BALANCE_TYPE_ID EFF_DATE            EXP_DATE                    BALANCE         CHARGE1        CHARGE2
--------------- --------------- ------------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
    CYCLE_UPPER     CYCLE_LOWER CYCLE_UPP CYCLE_LOW STATE     STATE_DATE                  ACCT_ID         SERV_ID
--------------- --------------- --------- --------- --------- ------------------- --------------- ---------------
  ITEM_GROUP_ID  OBJECT_TYPE_ID LOWER_BILLING_CYCLE_ID UPPER_BILLING_CYCLE_ID        PRIORITY
--------------- --------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------
              1               1 2018/07/28 00:07:33 2018/07/28 00:07:33               1               1              1
              1               1 UPP       LOW       STT       2018/07/28 00:07:33               1              1
              1               1                      1                      1               1


1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Is the second way wrong?
Should I use PREPARE every time?

Comment: What happens if you move the `commit` outside the loop too? Commit releases cursors though I'm not sure why it's relevant here, I'm a bit rusty on Pro*C...

Comment: I got same result.

Comment: Answer :: PUT this options `MODE=ANSI CLOSE_ON_COMMIT=NO` on Makefile and add `EXEC ORACLE OPTION (HOLD_CURSOR=YES);` on Source.

Comment: @P.Lonnie, instead of answering to a comment, answer to an answer (below). You'll earn some reputation points this way.

Comment: I'm still not sure why moving the commit outside the loop didn't help.